# How do you revert to drawing a combo box edit area in the default way in an OwnerDraw combo box?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have a derived class of `ComboBox` and override the `OnDrawItem` to custom draw the drop down list items.  How do I make the edit portion of the combo box (the part shown when the drop down is closed or at the top when the drop down is open) continue to draw in the way that a default `ComboBox` works?  Is there some way to call the base `ComboBox` functionality to draw the edit area portion, or is that unavailable when in OwnerDraw mode?  If it is unavailable, how do I simulate the look of the edit area portion for both `DropDown` and `DropDownList` styles?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET OwnerDraw ComboBox: Vista/7 themed DropDownList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891981/net-ownerdraw-combobox-vista-7-themed-dropdownlist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question actually covers two issues.

1. In order to target what data is displayed in the edit area of the combo box, use the State property of the event arguments in the OnDrawItem event, as so:

   ```
   Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawItem(e As DrawItemEventArgs)
       ' Draw the background of the item.
       e.DrawBackground()

       ' Skip doing anything else if the item doesn't exist.
       If e.Index = -1 Then Exit Sub

       If (e.State And DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit) = DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit Then
           ' Draw the contents of the edit area of the combo box.
       Else
           ' Draw the contents of an item in the drop down list.

           ' Draw the focus rectangle.
           e.DrawFocusRectangle()
       End If
   End Sub
   ```
2. OwnerDraw mode will not apply any visual style themes that the system is using, such as displaying the drop down arrow on a button face, changing the edit area to have a button face when in DropDownList style, etc.  All of that must be done by hand in the OnPaint event handler.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2891981/72873) implies that there is no out-of-the-box method call within the .NET framework for using the combo box visual styles, but there may be workarounds, or you can program the implementation of the styles by hand.

Answer (score 1):

The `DrawItemEventArgs` passed as `e` give you a few tools to work with.  To replicate something like what the system draws for you in `OwnerDraw` mode you can do something like this :

```
Public Class MyComboBox
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox

    Private _font As Font = New Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 9.0, _
                                                    FontStyle.Regular)

    Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawItem(e As DrawItemEventArgs)
        e.DrawBackground()
        If e.Index = -1 Then Exit Sub
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.Items(e.Index).ToString, _font, _
                              System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, _
                              New RectangleF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, _
                              e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height))
        e.DrawFocusRectangle()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**EDIT :**

If you mean to change the drawing behaviour of the displayed item versus the item as drawn in the drop-down area you can branch the drawing code based on the `DroppedDown` property :

```
 e.DrawBackground()
 If e.Index = -1 Then Exit Sub

 If Not Me.DroppedDown Then
     e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.Items(e.Index).ToString, _font, 
                           System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, _
                           New RectangleF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, _
                           e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height))

 Else
     ' do whatever you want - draw something else
     Dim rectangle As Rectangle = New Rectangle(2, e.Bounds.Top + 2, _
                                 e.Bounds.Height, e.Bounds.Height - 4)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, rectangle)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("foo...I'm item #" & e.Index, _font, _
                              System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, _
                              New RectangleF(e.Bounds.X + rectangle.Width, _
                              e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height))
 End If

 e.DrawFocusRectangle()
```

Likewise you can branch based on `If Me.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList ...` etc.  Handle each case in whichever way you like.  If you want gradients, themed elements, or other features provided by the OS-drawn component then you have to draw them yourself.

Comment: This looks to be how to simulate drawing items in the drop down area like the system would.  Maybe my question wasn't clear enough, but I was looking specifically for ways to draw the text box part, and only the text box part, the way the system would (while keeping in mind the differences in how the text box part looks between DropDown and DropDownList modes).

Comment: @MattHamsmith That is absolutely vague and unclear.  Could you try again?  Maybe post a picture of what you want to happen.

Comment: @MattHamsmith I've made a guess about what you're after...perhaps this?

Comment: This gave me the hint I needed to put me on the right track, but it isn't quite correct.  Me.DroppedDown indicates whether the combo box drop down is open.  To target the edit area of the combo box, as I have edited the question to indicate, you need (e.State And DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit) = DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit.